# Event target and rest operator with nodelist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have four buttons, each of these is different than others.
What I want:
When I click on the button I want to add to this button a class named 'togglemath' and exactly in the same time I want to remove class from the three left buttons ( of course if the buttons has a classname 'togglemath')

I know that the code below is bad, but I put this here to understand what I mean.

```
const sumButton = document.getElementById('add');
const substractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
const multipleButton = document.getElementById('multiple');
const divideButton = document.getElementById('divide');

const mathButtons = [sumButton, substractButton, multipleButton, divideButton];

const activeClass = () => {
     mathButtons.forEach(el => {
          el.addEventListener('click', e => {
               [e.target, ...rest] = mathButtons;
               e.target.classList.add('togglemath');
               rest.classList.remove('togglemath');
          });
     });
};
activeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make for example 3 buttons:

```
<button class="toggle">1</button>
<button class="toggle">2</button>
<button class="toggle">3</button>
<button class="toggle">4</button>
```

As far as I understand you need to remove class `togglemath` from all the buttons except the one that you clicked on. Then we can do something like this:

```
const TOGGLE_CLASS_NAME = 'togglemath';
const $buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');


function toggleClass(event) {
  for (const $button of $buttons) {
    $button.classList.remove(TOGGLE_CLASS_NAME);
  }

  event.target.classList.add(TOGGLE_CLASS_NAME);
}

for (const $button of $buttons) {
  $button.addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the class from all the elements when a button is clicked and then add the class to the clicked button:

```js
const sumButton = document.getElementById('add');
const substractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
const multipleButton = document.getElementById('multiple');
const divideButton = document.getElementById('divide');

const mathButtons = [sumButton, substractButton, multipleButton, divideButton];

mathButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', activeClass))

function activeClass() {
  mathButtons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('togglemath'));
  event.target.classList.add('togglemath');
}
```

```css
.togglemath {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>
<button id="subtract">subtract</button>
<button id="multiple">multiple</button>
<button id="divide">divide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not far from the actual solution. The problem seems to be with the understanding of the following line:

```
[e.target, ...rest] = mathButtons;
```

This doesn't search the `e.target` out of `mathButtons` and assigns the other elements to `rest`. But instead assigns `e.target` to the first element in `mathButtons` and `rest` to the second, third end fourth. This produces the follow-up problem that `e.target.classList.add('togglemath')` will always add the class to the first button.

`rest.classList.remove('togglemath')` has a somewhat other issue, namely that you try to access `classList` on an array. Instead you should access it for element in the array.

Without changing your code much you could be looking at something like this:

```
const sumButton = document.getElementById('add');
const substractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
const multipleButton = document.getElementById('multiple');
const divideButton = document.getElementById('divide');

const mathButtons = [sumButton, substractButton, multipleButton, divideButton];

const activeClass = () => {
     mathButtons.forEach(el => {
          el.addEventListener('click', e => {
               mathButtons.forEach(mathButton => {
                   mathButton.classList.remove('togglemath');
               });
               e.target.classList.add('togglemath');
          });
     });
};
activeClass();
```

This solution first removes all `togglemath` classes from all buttons. Then adds it (back) to the clicked target.

---

Strafing somewhat from what you've provided, you could opt to save the active button in a variable. This way you only have to remove the class from the current active button, add it to the event target, and replace the active variable with the clicked target.

```js
const sumButton = document.getElementById('add');
const substractButton = document.getElementById('subtract');
const multipleButton = document.getElementById('multiple');
const divideButton = document.getElementById('divide');

const mathButtons = [sumButton, substractButton, multipleButton, divideButton];

const activeClass = () => {
  let active;
  
  mathButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', event => {
      if (event.target === active) return;
      if (active) active.classList.remove('togglemath');
      event.target.classList.add('togglemath');
      active = event.target;
    });
  });
};
activeClass();
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid #33497b;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  background-color: white;
  color: #33497b;
}

button.togglemath {
  background-color: #33497b;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="add" type="button">+</button>
<button id="subtract" type="button">−</button>
<button id="multiple" type="button">×</button>
<button id="divide" type="button">÷</button>
```